# Mysql Linq There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

The exception occurs when a nested SELECT. If you comment out properties Photo, Birthday and Residence, then everything works. How do I rewrite the query to make it work?

```
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Persons>();
    var query = this._entity.Persons.AsExpandable();

                    #region 
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentPerson.PersonName))
                    {
                        predicate = predicate.And(i => i.PersonName.Contains(currentPerson.PersonName.Trim()));
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentPerson.PersonLastName))
                    {
                        predicate = predicate.And(i => i.PersonLastName.Contains(currentPerson.PersonLastName.Trim()));
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentPerson.PersonPatronymic))
                    {
                        predicate = predicate.And(i => i.PersonPatronymic.Contains(currentPerson.PersonPatronymic.Trim()));
                    }
    ...........

    var result = query.Where(predicate).AsEnumerable().Select(o => new POCO.PersonResult
  {
    Id        = (int)o.Id,
    Photo     = o.persons_photos.Select(s => s.PersonFrontView).FirstOrDefault(),
    FullName  = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", o.PersonLastName, o.PersonName, o.PersonPatronymic),
    Birthday  = o.persons_passport_data.Select(s => s.PersonBirthday).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
    Residence = o.persons_registration
                                    .Select(s =>
                                            String.Join(", ", ListModel.GetCountry(s.PersonCountryId),
                                                              ListModel.GetRegion(s.PersonRegionId),
                                                              ListModel.GetCity(s.PersonCityId))).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like MySql connector does not support MARS (Multiple active result sets) and your LINQ to Objects query (after `AsEnumerable()` call) is involving lazy loading (`o.persons_photos`, `o.persons_passport_data` and `o.persons_registration` navigation properties) which require additional readers while the main data reader is still executing.

The best would be to let the whole query execute as single SQL query by removing the `AsEnumerable()` call, but since the projection is using unsupported methods, I guess the only option is to replace the `AsEnumerable()` call with `ToList()`, which will ensure the main data reader is complete at the time navigation properties are lazy loaded.

Another thing you can try is to eager load them (assuming you are using EF) by adding a couple `Include` calls:

```
var query = this._entity.Persons
    .Include(o => o.persons_photos)
    .Include(o => o.persons_passport_data)
    .Include(o => o.persons_registration)
    .AsExpandable();

// the rest (same as yours) ...
```

Comment: Is Multiple active result sets an option murash?  Otherwise I was thinking the include option as well.

Comment: The quick Google for "MySQL MARS" shows that they are not supported (hence cannot be turned on as for MSSQL provider etc.)