# How can I select special Index of model in View?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, datareader

I use this query in controller for creating a list from join four tables:

```
var ViewModel = (from APP in db1.application
                 where APP.APP_STATUS == "TO_DO"
                 join APPDEL in db1.app_delegation on APP.APP_UID equals APPDEL.APP_UID
                 join Con in db1.content on APPDEL.TAS_UID equals Con.CON_ID
                 join BPMNPRC in db1.bpmn_process on APPDEL.PRO_UID equals BPMNPRC.PRJ_UID
                 join RUSRE in db1.rbac_users on APP.APP_INIT_USER equals RUSRE.USR_UID
                 where APPDEL.TAS_UID == Con.CON_ID 
                    && Con.CON_CATEGORY == ("TAS_TITLE")
                    && APP.APP_UID == APPDEL.APP_UID 
                    && APPDEL.DEL_THREAD_STATUS == "OPEN" 
                    && APPDEL.USR_UID == bpmUseid.BPMSID
                 select new ApplicationContentViewModel
                         {
                             creator = RUSRE,
                             app_delegation = APPDEL,
                             application = APP,
                             content = Con,
                             task = BPMNPRC,
                         }).AsEnumerable();
return View(ViewModel);
```

But I need to select a special record in `APPDEL` (app_delegation), then retrieve name of this record.

I use this command in view for selecting item by field of `DEL_INDEX`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <th>                                                    
  @(item.app_delegation.DEL_INDEX == Model.Max(x => x.app_delegation.DEL_INDEX) - 1 ? item.creator.USR_LASTNAME : "");
 </th>  
}
```

In fact, I want to select the max value of `DEL_INDEX - 1`, and retrieve its last name.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException:: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> Inner Exception:
>
> MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

How can I handle this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `ToList()` method instead of `AsEnumerable()` before executing expression `Model.Max(x => x.app_delegation.DEL_INDEX)` as shown below:

```
var ViewModel = (from APP in db1.application
                 where APP.APP_STATUS == "TO_DO"
                 join APPDEL in db1.app_delegation on APP.APP_UID equals APPDEL.APP_UID
                 join Con in db1.content on APPDEL.TAS_UID equals Con.CON_ID
                 join BPMNPRC in db1.bpmn_process on APPDEL.PRO_UID equals BPMNPRC.PRJ_UID
                 join RUSRE in db1.rbac_users on APP.APP_INIT_USER equals RUSRE.USR_UID
                 where APPDEL.TAS_UID == Con.CON_ID 
                 && Con.CON_CATEGORY == ("TAS_TITLE")
                 && APP.APP_UID == APPDEL.APP_UID 
                 && APPDEL.DEL_THREAD_STATUS == "OPEN" 
                 && APPDEL.USR_UID == bpmUseid.BPMSID
                 select new ApplicationContentViewModel
                 {
                     creator = RUSRE,
                     app_delegation = APPDEL,
                     application = APP,
                     content = Con,
                     task = BPMNPRC,
                 }).ToList(); // here is the change
```

**Explanation**

By calling `AsEnumerable()` the data reader is kept open and when executing `Model.Max()` as LINQ to Objects throws exception due to MySQL Connector you're using doesn't have support for MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) yet. Using `ToList()` methods ensures the data reader operation is completed when lazy loading checks all navigation properties.

**Side note:**

Assumed you're using EF, try eager loading with [`Include()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) to add related objects in single statement when dealing with multiple queries.

Similar issue:

[Mysql Linq There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444524/mysql-linq-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connection-w)

Comment: I correct it. The error was removed,but in I couldn't display my favorite item. Can you help me for displaying the name of item which value of `DEL_INDEX` equal to maximum DEL_INDEX of all records -1.